# Computing the surface integral of a multivariate function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

The problem reads:

> Find $ \int_S \, f(x, z) \, dS $, where $ f(x, z) = e^{-(x^2 + z^2)} $ and $S$ is the unit disk centered at the point $(0, 2, 0)$ and in the plane $y=2$.

I'm not sure how to set up this problem because of where the surface is placed in $ \mathbb{R}^3 $.

Comment: Firstly, how would you parametrize S? Note that on the xz axis, S is really just a unit circle centred on the origin. Hence the go to form of parametrization would be polar, or anything similar to it.

Answer (score 0):

Parmaterize your surface

$x = r\cos \theta, z = r\sin \theta, y = 2\\
\|dS\| = \|(\frac {\partial x}{\partial r},\frac {\partial y}{\partial r},\frac {\partial z}{\partial r})\times(\frac {\partial x}{\partial \theta},\frac {\partial y}{\partial \theta},\frac {\partial z}{\partial \theta})\| \ dr\ d\theta\\
\|dS\| = r\ dr\ d\theta$

$\iint re^{-r^2} \ dr\ d\theta$

Comment: I took the cross product of $\langle \cos \theta, 0, \sin \theta \rangle$ and $\langle -u \sin \theta, 0, u \cos \theta \rangle$, and I got $\langle 0, u \cos(2\theta), 0 \rangle$. Taking the norm of this result yields $u \cos(2\theta)$. An I doing something wrong?

Comment: check it again,  you lost track of a sign.  You should have $(0, u\cos^2\theta + u\sin^2\theta, 0) = (0,u,0)$